# Jquery Validations when using Zend Framework

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework, jquery-validate

I am Using zend Framework-1.7.2. when I am Updating Account Information of logged in user that time I am using jquery validations. But the script is not working.

How to use it? Please, anyone can help me ?

**I am not using Zend Jquery Plugin. I am using seperate Jquery script like we are including and using in any simple php project.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zfdebug, or somehow included twice the Jquery script, you may have problems from that. I had theese kind of problems.

Comment: Sorry, actually i was busy so i couldn't see your answer. Jquery script is not included twice. it is included once in header file. and that script is working for Registration page. similar to registration page, i am using the code in update account page. But its not working.